# What kind of .NET query language is this?

Tags: .net, sql, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm wondering what kind of .NET query language the following is:

```
tableName.Select(e => e.PartitionKey == „KeyX“).ToList().OrderBy(e => e.SomeValue).Take(25)
```

I found it as example for querying Windows Azure Storage Tables.

Has this thing a name and can it also be used with SQL instead of Azure Storage Tables, is it something included in .NET or some extra library?

Thank you

Comment: Off-topic: Note that in this particular query, it seems like `Select` (which projects/maps each element to a new value) should really be `Where` (which filters values based on some criterion). Otherwise you'd be sorting a list of `bool`s by their `.SomeValue` property (which doesn't exist) and then fetch the first <= 25 of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx), although I think your query is *slightly* messed up. It's a huge topic, but really important. There are different LINQ implementations to work with in-process collections, SQL, appropriate REST-like web services etc.

Note that there's directly anguage support too:

```
// Wouldn't work in this particular case - see below
var query = (from e in tableName
             where e.PartitionKey == "KeyX"
             orderby e.SomeValue
             select e).Take(25);
```

Note that the `ToList()` in the query in the question forces the Azure part to be executed immediately and the results fetched to the client as a `List<T>`. It can *then* be ordered and limited on the client. I'd normally use `AsEnumerable()` for that instead (which forces the remainder of the query to be done in LINQ to Objects, but without immediately materializing into a `List`), but `ToList` is another option.

Comment: Argh, I already supposed that, but it didn't make sense to me since linq looks different to me: `var pageObject = (from op in db.ObjectPermissions
                  join pg in db.Pages on op.ObjectPermissionName equals page.PageName
                  where pg.PageID == page.PageID
                  select op)
                 .SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: @alapeno: That's just syntactic sugar, basically, in the form of *query expressions*. It compiles down to the same set of calls. See my Edulinq post on them for more information: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx

Comment: Thank you! Accept your answer in 10 minutes, not allowed to accept it earlier.

Comment: @JonSkeet - just one clarification: Windows Azure Table Storage only supports a subset of query operators. It doesn't support `orderby`, which is why the OP's query has orderby following `ToList()`. See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135725.aspx) for supported/unsupported query operators on Table Storage.

Comment: Agree with David.  Linq statement looks good.  ATS can't support OrderBy and the Take() logic is dependent upon OrderBy

Comment: @DavidMakogon: Excellent, thanks. Will edit to add that. (I'd normally use AseEnumerable instead.) On the other hand, wouldn't the first `Select` normally be `Where` instead?

Answer (score 2):

`.Select(…)`, `.ToList()`, `.OrderBy(…)`, and `.Take(…)` are [**LINQ query operators**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337893.aspx).

They are implemented as extension methods for the `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` types. For the former, they reside in the static [`System.Linq.Enumerable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx); for the latter, they are defined in the [`System.Linq.Queryable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx). Because these methods return the same type as the one they're operating on, they allow method chaining: `.Select(…).ToList().OrderBy(…).Take(…)`.

---

**LINQ**, in short, is a declarative API (with strong roots in functional programming) that was introduced in .NET 3.5. It's main purpose is querying sequences and collections of all sorts: in-memory object collections, XML documents, SQL databases, network data sources, etc. It was made possible by several extensions to the C# and VB.NET languages, among them:

- extension methods, e.g.:

  ```
  static class Enumerable
  {
      public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> xs)
      {                          // ^^^^
          foreach (T x in xs)
          {
              return false;
          }
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```

  Which makes it possible to write:

  ```
  // List<int> numbers = …;
  numbers.IsEmpty()
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  Enumerable.IsEmpty(numbers)
  ```
- improved type inference
- new, more compact `=>` syntax for anonymous delegates (lambda functions).

  ```
  delegate (int x, int y) { return x == y; }  // only this was valid in C# 2
        (int x, int y) => { return x == y; } 
        (int x, int y) => x == y; 

  (int x) => x > 0 
        x => x > 0
  ```
- expressions and expression trees (i.e. the compiler can output source code as an AST data structure instead of as CIL "bytecode"; see the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace)
- syntax transformations / query comprehension syntax:

  ```
  from x in xs where W select S
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  xs.Where(x => W).Select(x => S)
  ```

  which in turn becomes:

  ```
  // using System.Linq
  Enumerable.Select(Enumerable.Where(xs, x => W), x => S)
  ```